# Junit testcase for a method with Graphics parameter

Tags: java, junit, graphics2d

I' trying to make testcases in junit for my snake game.
I have a gameover method and I'm trying to test it:

```
    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
    String msg = "Game Over";
    final Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(small);
    g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2,
                 HEIGHT / 2);
    }
```

My main class is Board and it extends JPanel. The test:

```
    public void testGameOver() {
    System.out.println("gameOver");
    Board instance = new Board();
    Graphics g = instance.getGraphics();
    instance.gameOver(g);
    Color tmp = new Color(instance.getBackground().getRGB());
    assertEquals(tmp,Color.white.getRGB());
    assertEquals(instance.getFont().getFontName(),new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14).getFontName());
    }
```

I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to run the gameOver method on instance. Please help!! I'm new at Junit.

```
Testcase: testGameOver(snake.BoardTest):    Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at snake.Board.gameOver(Board.java:121)
at snake.BoardTest.testGameOver(BoardTest.java:67)
```

Comment: Please post the error stacktrace that includes the java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into details, you can provide a [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) of `Graphics` object.

For example, using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

```
@Test 
public void shouldUpdateGraphicsToGameOver(){
    Graphics gMock = Mockito.mock(Graphics.class);
    //expectations
    Color expectedColor = Color.white;
    Font expectedFont= ...;
    String expectedMsg = ...;
    int expectedWidth = ...;
    int expectedHeight = ...;

    classUnderTest.gameOver(gMock);

    Mockito.verify(gMock).setColor(expectedColor);
    Mockito.verify(gMock).setFont(expectedFont);
    Mocktio.verify(gMock).drawString(expectedMsg, expectedWidth, expectedHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a Graphics instance by calling `getGraphics()` on a component, almost always a bad idea, since the Graphics object thus obtained is never long-lasting, and doing it **before** the component has been rendered, a horrific idea. So don't be surprised that it's null.

Solution: you should only work with Graphic objects passed into `paintComponnt(Graphics g)` method overrides, or if obtained from a BufferedImage, that's it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it.. To run the method gameOver I must first have a value for g. Please explain. I have never used paintComponent. How about if I just override paint?

Comment: If you wanted to do this without making a mock Graphics object as the accepted answer suggests, I would do it using a BufferedImage, whose createGraphics() method always returns a valid Graphics object.